# Wget redirects even though robots are off

Tags: web-scraping, wget

I'm using wget to download data for a research project on far-right extremism. I have a list of urls, but the urls are not downloaded. (They do work in the browser.)

The urls are all structured like this:

```
https://www.forum.org/forum/printthread.php?t=1182735&pp=100
```

But wget redirects to the front page. However, these urls work fine with wget:

```
https://www.forum.org/forum/printthread.php?t=1182735
```

The problem seems to be the last bit of the url, `&pp=100`.

Things I've tried thus far:

1. Escape the `&` character (`\&`) or replace it with `%` or `%20`.
2. Turn off robots.

Here's the wget code I use:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel -j 4 wget -e robots=off --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --random-wait --max-redirect=0 -P forumfiles -a wget_log_15dec2018
```

Edit: for what it's worth, the urls download with HTTrack. Which makes me even more curious about this wget issue.

Edit2: changed original urls for anonymity.

Edit3: thanks to the answer below, the following code works:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel -j 4 wget --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge --load-cookies cookies.txt -nc --keep-session-cookies  -U "Mozilla/5.0" --random-wait --max-redirect=0 -P forumfiles -a wget_log_17dec2018
```

Comment: When I observe the top right corner of the page, I notice that there are only 3 pages. Each page has 10 posts (pp = 10). Hence, (pp=100) which is 10th page, is redirecting you to the home page because the page doesnt exist. This is my understanding.

Comment: If so, why does the 100-page url work in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly the website example you've provided returns results based on the `user-agent` string. With the default user-agent, the server returns a 301 response and asks wget to download only the first page.

You can simply change the user-agent string to make it work. e.g.:
`--user-agent=mozilla`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for the help Darnir!